# How can verifying digital signature in bitcoin transaction?

Tags: digital-signature, bitcoin

I understand that Bitcoin protocol is based on an asymmetric cryptography.

Regarding digitally signed transaction, I understand the Verification Process of bitcoin transaction which is explained in Bitcoin Wiki. 
(https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Verification)

By the way, I've read some article about 'bitcoin transaction verification' by chance.
-> https://medium.com/@aalim.khan/bitcoin-transactions-scripts-and-digital-signatures-506688e1630a

While reading the article, questions arose about the following image.

https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*zJ_GgIr2YEZGs74BTfyB_A.png

The image depict that some kind of verification process.

But, I couldn't find a comparing process of the image in bitcoin wiki or source code.

The image describes these below 2 transactions are equal, then the signature can be verified.

- Transaction Hash that is decrypted by public key

- Transaction Hash that is double hashed of requested transaction

Is there anybody who can explain? Is above process really working in bitcoin?

Answer (score -1):

I've found bitcoin source code of validating that the transaction is not tampered.

See below link:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.16.2/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1264